# How to create seed64 pattern for RFC6238?

Tags: java, byte, password-encryption

I'm following the [RFC DOCUMENTATION](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) to implement the algorithm in Java. Using the same test token shared value `1234567890`    [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238#appendix-B) and I got the same results.

But I don't understand the `seed32`, `seed64` pattern, in the example, we have patterns like this :

```
  // Seed for HMAC-SHA1 - 20 bytes
         String seed = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930";
         // Seed for HMAC-SHA256 - 32 bytes
         String seed32 = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "313233343536373839303132";
         // Seed for HMAC-SHA512 - 64 bytes
         String seed64 = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "31323334";
```

And:

```
3132333435363738393031323334353637383930
```

Is the HEX value of ASCII string :

```
12345678901234567890
```

Let's suppose I have this ASCII string :

```
aaa.bbbbbbbb.ccc@gmail.comAAAABBBBBCCCCCCDDD
```

The equivalent HEX is :

```
6161612e62626262626262622e63636340676d61696c2e636f6d414141414242424242434343434343444444
```

So how do I get the seed, seed 32, seed 64 from this HEX result?

```
string seed="what's the seed value"

string seed32="what's the seed32 value"

string seed64="what's the seed64 value"
```